# Delete associate in one to many grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have two entities in grails project

```
class Author {
    String name

    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    String title
    int year
    String isbn
}
```

When i delete Book i need delete author and associate table references

But when i do Book.delete(id) i was this stacktrace

```
{"errors":"Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `belongsTo` to the book to tell GORM to cascade delete http://docs.grails.org/3.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

Or use the ORM dsl for more options http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/index.html in section `8.2.9. Custom Cascade Behaviour`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just be able to delete the Book (and not actually delete the Author and all related books as well) then you need to do something like:

Change your Book class to have a reference to the author:

```
class Book {
    String title
    int year
    String isbn

    Author author
    static belongsTo = Author
}
```

Then remove the book from the author before deleting it:

```
Book b = ? // get your book however you want here
def author = b.author
author.removeFromBooks(b)
b.delete()
```

Comment: FYI... If you are going to have both `Author author` and `static belongsTo = Author` in the `Book` class, we provide a shorthand way to express that and that is to use `static belongsTo = [author: Author]`.  If you do that, you don't have to declare the `Author author` property, it will be added automatically.